# A error occured when calculate the centroid of geometric in R

Tags: r, r-sf, centroid

I use the code below to calculate the geometric's centroid:

```
libaray(sf)
city_map <- st_read("~\\city.shp")
city_map<-sf::st_transform(city_map,crs=4326)
city_center <-city_map %>%
  sf::st_centroid()
```

But I always get this error:

```
Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 0 is not valid: Non-empty, non-full loops must have at least 3 vertices
```

I would really appreciate your help on this matter
Many thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but currently the problem you are struggling with is not reproducible by others, though your issue is most likely the shapefile itself. If you can't share the `city.shp`, you can try to simplify it first and include `dput()` output of simplified sf object ( `dput(st_simplify(city_map, dTolerance = 5000))`, where dTolerance is in meters ).

Comment: It might be worth trying `city_map <- st_make_valid(city_map)` to repair the error in the shapefile

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps. I removed some `shp` files and the error just disappeared. But I did't find difference between the romved files and retained files. I try to use both your code, but it didn't work. But anyway, thank you for your help.@margusl  , @Andrew Gustar